# Can I travel back to the UK from Middle East with transit in Amsterdam with 4 months left on my British passport?

Tags: transit, paperwork, uk-citizens, netherlands

Can I travel back to the UK from Middle East with transit in Amsterdam with 4 months left on my British passport ?

Comment: Is it a single ticket or separate?

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you're travelling on a single ticket**, UK entry requirements is what matters - the Netherlands doesn't impose any document requirements of its own for transit.

TIMATIC, the database used by airlines, states:

> Passengers with a British passport with nationality  British Citizen  are allowed to enter with an expired passport.

Now, the Middle Eastern country likely won't let you exit on an expired passport, but no country imposes a 3/6-month requirement for foreigners *exiting*.

As such, you're all good, before and after the "definite" Brexit.

Comment: (+1) That's an important point but what about the situation after January?

Comment: @Relaxed Won't affect a thing, as again, it's a mere *connection* at AMS, unless it's on separate tickets

Comment: That may very well be but mentioning it improved the answer IMO, as it is not self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

Providing you travel on or before 31 December 2020, your passport should be valid for the proposed duration of your stay; you do not need any additional period of validity on your passport beyond this.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/netherlands/entry-requirements

From 1 January 2021, on the day you travel, you’ll need your passport to both:

- have at least 6 months left
- be less than 10 years old (even if it has 6 months or more left)

Source: https://www.gov.uk/visit-europe-1-january-2021

Comment: (+1) Having six months left is probably safer/easier in practice but the actual rule in article 6(1)(a)(i) of the [Schengen Borders code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20190611) is three months after the date of intended departure. The six-month advice probably comes from adding the 90-day maximum stay allowed under short-stay rules to the 3-month buffer required on entry but with a clear plan to leave on a the same day and a ticket to support it, transit should be allowed with 4 months left on the passport.

Comment: (-1) Transit in the Netherlands isn't subject to Dutch entry requirements. Were it not for Middle Eastern exit immigration, OP could travel with an *expired* passport. This is unless the trip is on separate tickets

Comment: @Crazydre That's a good point and the article I cited doesn't apply to airside transit but transit in the Netherlands is definitely subject to Dutch and EU law (case in point: the airport transit visa requirement). It's not true that UK entry requirements are all that matters in principle. Will airside transit still be possible with an expired passport after January 2021?

Comment: @S Williams To get a better answer it would be helpful if you edited your question to clarify when you’ll be travelling and whether you’ll transit air or landside.

Comment: @Relaxed If 1) the airport has a transit corridor **and** 2) no airport transit visa is required **and** 3) the trip is in a single reservation, then only the destination's entry requirements are relevant. This applies worldwide except in Canada, China, Mauritius and South Africa. So no, the definite Brexit won't change OPs case.

Comment: @Crazydre That's not how the law works, the local rules are always relevant, they provide for the transit corridor, (lack of) visa requirements, etc. To the extent that transit with an expired passport is possible, it is thanks to those rules, not because they are not relevant. The mere fact that there are some exceptions (transit visas, the countries you mentioned) further underlines this.

Comment: For all I know, it will still be possible to transit with an expired passport in the Netherlands, I don't know those rules or where they are defined. But it won't be because only the destination's entry requirements are relevant, hence my question.

Comment: @Relaxed Both yes and no. As a related example, I can transit airports (with a transit corridor) in e.g. Belarus, Russia and Qatar on my EU ID card, and those countries certainly don't have any rules allowing this; rather it's allowed because, with an onward flight in the same booking, only the destination's rules are relevant. Some countries can have specific transit rules, as I've mentioned, but the majority don't (other than connection time limits)

Comment: @Crazydre I see what you mean and I think the distinction between our points of view is mostly academic at this point. The important thing is that for that to happen, the country must be allowing transit corridors, have no visa requirement for transit passengers (and that typically comes with constraints like having an onward ticket or, as you just mentioned, connection times), no APIS (or if they do then an established practice of tolerating other documents or incomplete records if someone has an onward ticket). All these rules do matter.

Comment: Either way, countries are in principle allowed to impose any number of requirements and it's interesting to confirm that they don't for a specific scenario.

Comment: @Relaxed TIMATIC states whenever a country does impose particular transit requirements. Whenever it only says e.g. "Visa not required, except for passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours." then in terms of identity/travel documents, only the destination's requirements apply (again, provided it's on a single ticket).

Comment: @Crazydre Sure, TIMATIC covers both set of requirements. What does have to do with the earlier discussion? If only the destination's requirements applied, you wouldn't even look the transit requirements up or check whether it said anything.

Comment: @Relaxed For the vast majority of countries the text will be something of the sort unless there's no transit corridor. In other words, the vast majority of countries impose no requirements other than having an onward ticket within a max number of hours as well as the papers for the destination. Meaning, in practice, that if having a single ticket with a connection at an airport with a transit corridor, the destination is what matters.